# Confusion about multiparticle state using tensor product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Excuse me if this is too naive a question or too trivial. In this [lecture note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_08.pdf) from MIT QM II course, I don't see how the first equality in the 2nd and 3rd equation of equation (1.19) follows, that is, I don't see how you get $|+\rangle\otimes|+\rangle$ there in the middle. The calculation is supposed go like this (for the 2nd equation of (1.19)): $S_z^T |+\rangle \otimes |-\rangle= (S_z\otimes 1 + 1\otimes S_z)(|+\rangle \otimes |-\rangle)=S_z |+\rangle \otimes|-\rangle +|+\rangle \otimes S_z|-\rangle = (\frac{\hbar}{2}-\frac{\hbar}{2})|+\rangle\otimes|- \rangle = 0$ , right?

But I get $|+\rangle\otimes|- \rangle$ here, not $|+\rangle\otimes|+ \rangle$. Am I doing something wrong or is it a typo in the lecture note? Could someone please clarify this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you are right, your calculation is correct, it is just a typo in the first equality with the tensor product but at the end the answer is still zero. You can convince of this even by reading the notes:

"One can derive this result quickly by noting that since $S_z^{(1)}$ is diagonal in the first basis and $S_z^{(2)}$ is diagonal in the second basis, the total $S_z^T$ is diagonal in the tensor space basis and its eigenvalue acting on a tensor state is the sum of the $S_z$ eigenvalues for particle one and particle two."

That is what you did step by step in your calculation, adding the eigenvalues. The eigenvectors would remain the same (as you showed), so in the second line we should have $(\hbar/2-\hbar/2)|+\rangle \otimes |-\rangle$ and in the third line we should have $(-\hbar/2+\hbar/2)|-\rangle \otimes |+\rangle$.